# Is there any way to read back the closed chat?

Tags: discussion, comments, chat

Often after long comments for any question, we get `switch to chat` option....

Assuming a scenario (*there might be other scenarios too*) that : 
 The user, closed the chat and the OP of answer deleted the answer(*which had the chat link*), can i re-view that chat again...i mean, is it saved somewhere under my account similar to `received comments` history or `posted answers`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, just go to your user profile on the exchange you want (Stack Overflow in this case), and then prefix the url with `chat.` and it will take you to your chat profile page.

Here is the [url for yours](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/2972107/noobeditor)

There you can see things like your recent rooms, a list of your recent messages, and a history of your conversations. It shows two that you have (one with Mr. Alien and one with Jan Dvorak).

Comment: awesome...thankx mate!! :)